# In Google Sheets, how to check if Cell A (Date) is within the Date range of Cell B and C

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet with a timeline that shows a month per row in column A and an amount in USD next to that month in column B.

I want to be able to specify amounts in column G with a start and end date for that amount in columns E and F.

What I am trying to achieve is that the values in column B are automatically calculated by looking at the start and end dates specified in columns E and F and then taking the corresponding value from column G if the date in column A falls in between the date range specified in E and F.

I have found many suggestions for similar problems online but wasn't able to get any of them to work for my specific case. Any help is very welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it as an array formula like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(mmult((text(indirect("A2:A"&count(A2:A)+1),"YYMM")>=text(TRANSPOSE(indirect("`E3:E"&count(E3:E)+2)),"YYMM"))*(text(indirect("A2:A"&count(A2:A)+1),"YYMM")<=text(transpose(indirect("F3:F"&count(F3:F)+2)),"YYMM"))*transpose(indirect("G3:G"&count(G3:G)+2)),(INDIRECT("G3:G"&count(G3:G)+2)+2)^0))
```

The idea is to develop a 2D array where the rows are the months and the columns are the amounts for matching time periods. Then use the standard Mmult method to get the row totals of the array.

Using indirect for the ranges makes the formula longer but using full-column references would be slow as it would result in a nearly 1000 X 1000 array for a default-sized sheet.

[image]

**EDIT 1**

Or shorter

```
=ArrayFormula(mmult((text(indirect("A2:A"&count(A2:A)+1),"YYMM")>=text(TRANSPOSE(indirect("E3:E"&count(E3:E)+2)),"YYMM"))
*(text(indirect("A2:A"&count(A2:A)+1),"YYMM")<=text(transpose(indirect("F3:F"&count(F3:F)+2)),"YYMM"))
,INDIRECT("G3:G"&count(G3:G)+2)))
```

because you can combine the row totals step with multiplication by column G.

**EDIT 2**

Alternatively you could just employ a much simpler pull-down formula using SUMIFS:

```
=ArrayFormula(sumifs(G$3:G,eomonth(E$3:E,-1)+1,"<="&A2,F$3:F,">="&A2))
```

This uses Eomonth to change all the start dates to the first of the month so they can be compared to the dates in column A correctly. The formula still has to be entered as an array formula because of the Eomonth calculation.

**Note**

The equivalent pull-down formula to the original array formulas above would be

```
=ArrayFormula(sumifs(G$3:G,text(E$3:E,"YYMM"),"<="&text(A2,"YYMM"),text(F$3:F,"YYMM"),">="&text(A2,"YYMM")))
```

but this gives zero for all rows - the reason for this is not obvious to me at time of writing.

Comment: Thank you, this is way beyond my capabilities, but as long as it works, I don't really have to understand it :)

Comment: I agree, it is a bit gnarly! I will add a much simpler pull-down formula that some users may be more comfortable with.

Comment: Thanks so much for your effort! I will try the updated Formular first thing tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you for that, it is just perfect